# Jasper query (oracle) Non suported SQL92 token

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have problem when try execute sql query eg.

```
Select * from test
where $X{IN, id,PARAM_1} order by id, seq_order  //not working

Select * from test
where id in ('1','2','3') order by id, seq_order //working
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check log files to get more details? The `$X{IN}` is a right expression that works well for different DB. What version of JSS are you using? Which version of jdbc driver and Oracle DB are you using?

Comment: BTW, what language did you set?

Comment: @AlexK Sorry but  I'don understand you which language and where?

Comment: At JSS query dialog (combobox)

Comment: @AlexK  Language is sql, error --> https://i.postimg.cc/ydK2fkH2/error-det.jpg